# Renumber field disable auto increment

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to disable auto increment so that I can renumber a field with out the AI?

I'm trying this, but it doesn't seem to be working properly:

```
ALTER TABLE `x`.`billadr` 
CHANGE COLUMN `AutoInc` `AutoInc` 
INT(11) NOT NULL ;
```

Comment: Why do you want to renumber it without AI?

Comment: I want to control the way a customer gets renumbered.

Comment: Even though a column is auto_increment you can still specify the value of that colulmn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ALTER TABLE `x`.`billadr` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1234;
```

If you want to *remove* `AUTO_INCREMENT` then just redefine the column without it:

```
ALTER TABLE `x`.`billadr` CHANGE `AutoInc` `AutoInc` INT(11) NOT NULL
```

Otherwise, create a **new** column, copy/renumber as needed.

Comment: @user2132252 Yes, but *"You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that have already been used"* ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html))

Comment: I'll leave this here: somehow my `auto_increment` got stuck at 18446744073709551615 (2^63-1) and the `AUTO_INCREMENT = N` query wouldn't change this. Removing the auto_increment attribute from the PK column as shown then adding it again fixed it.

Comment: @zneak if you have a `auto_increment` value that high, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Of course there was something wrong. This is not criticism on your answer, I'm just saying "I had this problem and the steps in your answer helped me solve it." What happened is that, in a local environment, I created a new row with phpMyAdmin and set its id to -1 after the fact. I then used phpMyAdmin to decrement the auto_increment value back to something like 149, and then it somehow got stuck to 2^63 instead, and the query to change it wouldn't do anything anymore. I had to remove the auto_increment attribute and add it again.